# Regex: Minimum 13 characters and WITHIN 13 characters maximum 3 characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I need an expression that validates, something like this:

**1234-567.890-123**

- *Min* 13 numbers
- *Max* 3 Special Characters ("-" and .) <-- no matter where

My solution `[0-9]{13,}[-\.]{0,3}`can't work as this only validates:

1234567890123.-.

Comment: Try this: ([0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{3})

Comment: can you specify the language you are using?

Comment: if ordering of characters does not matter use `^(?=(?:[\d.-]){13,}$)(?=(?:\D*\d){13,})(?!(?:[^.-]*[.-]){4}).*$`

Comment: I wonder why someone downvoted the question? Any explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ordering of characters in string do not matters, you can use

```
^(?=(?:[\d.-]){13,}$)(?=(?:\D*\d){13,})(?!(?:[^.-]*[.-]){4}).*$
```

*Regex Breakdown*

```
^ #Starting of string
 (?=(?:[\d.-]){13,}$) #Lookahead which sees that the string only contains digits, . and -
 (?=(?:\D*\d){13,}) #Lookahead to match 13 digits
 (?!(?:[^.-]*[.-]){4}) #Looahead so that the number of . and - are not equal to 4
 .*
$
```

*Middle Part*

```
(?= #Lookahead
   (?:\D*\d) #Match all non-digits and then digit.
   {13,} #Repeat this at least 13 times.In simple words, it is matching at least 13 digits.
)
```

Comment: Thanks, your option was what I needed. I just don't understand the middle and why it's needed? ```(?=(?:\D*\d){13,})```  Maybe you can comment on it? Thanks.

Comment: @AmirRahbaran added an explanation..see if it helps

Comment: It helped a lot. I'm sure this answer is going to be very useful for future googlers ;) thanks a bunch.